# Front Facing Camera Issue in IPhone 5S IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, avfoundation, front-camera

I have problem on IPhone 5S with front camera output, the same session resolution like rear camera. (`AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288`) and `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` setting for `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`.
I found some discussion on apple forum about exact issue, here is the link: [https://discussions.apple.com/message/23079639#23079639](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23150694#23150694)

What is the problem?
Please Help.

Good output, rear-facing camera.

```
Printing description of imageBuffer:
<CVPixelBuffer 0xd5e2f30 width=352 height=288 pixelFormat=420v iosurface=0xd80e724 planes=2>
<Plane 0 width=352 height=288 bytesPerRow=352>
<Plane 1 width=176 height=144 bytesPerRow=352>
<attributes=<CFBasicHash 0xd5c3710 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf971b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "PixelFormatDescription"} = <CFBasicHash 0xb9fce0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf97164 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97194 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "OpenGLESCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    3 : <CFString 0x3bf972c4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ContainsAlpha"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e88 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = false}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf97184 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    7 : <CFString 0x3bf972d4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "Planes"} = <CFArray 0xb24830 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <CFBasicHash 0xb99420 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf973b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0xba06a0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 12, capacity = 12, bytes = 0x00000000917cbb3100000000}
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf97334 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BlackBlock"} = <CFData 0xb9deb0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 1, capacity = 1, bytes = 0x10}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97324 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BitsPerBlock"} = <CFNumber 0xb277e0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

    1 : <CFBasicHash 0xba0e50 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf97334 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BlackBlock"} = <CFData 0xb9c550 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 2, capacity = 2, bytes = 0x8080}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97344 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "HorizontalSubsampling"} = <CFNumber 0xc0f720 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +2, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    4 : <CFString 0x3bf97324 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BitsPerBlock"} = <CFNumber 0xba0e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +16, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf973b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0xba16d0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 12, capacity = 12, bytes = 0x00000000817bbb3100000000}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf97354 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "VerticalSubsampling"} = <CFNumber 0xc0f720 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +2, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

)}
    8 : <CFString 0x3bf97294 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "PixelFormat"} = <CFNumber 0xb7acf0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +875704438, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    12 : <CFString 0x3bf97174 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
}

}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x126e2130 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf70edc [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "MetadataDictionary"} = <CFBasicHash 0xd5da1a0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf70f4c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "SNR"} = <CFNumber 0xd5da1d0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +33.11550123401803347178, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf70ddc [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "sensorDGain"} = <CFNumber 0xd58def0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +256, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x3bf70f3c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "SensorID"} = <CFNumber 0x126f7b40 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +356, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf7054c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ExposureTime"} = <CFNumber 0xd5d83d0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +0.03332500000000000046, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
    7 : <CFString 0x3bf70dec [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ispDGain"} = <CFNumber 0xd54d620 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +273, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    11 : <CFString 0x3bf7017c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "AGC"} = <CFNumber 0xd5e21f0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +780, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    12 : <CFString 0x3bf7114c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "AEAverage"} = <CFNumber 0xd5e27a0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +126, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

    3 : <CFString 0x3bf96f54 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0xd5c34b0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_601_4"}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf96f94 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x126bced0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf96fd4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0xd58dfa0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x126e2100 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
>
```

Bad output, front-facing camera.

```
Printing description of imageBuffer:
<CVPixelBuffer 0x12638980 width=352 height=288 pixelFormat=420v iosurface=0xd80e724 planes=2>
<Plane 0 width=352 height=288 bytesPerRow=384>
<Plane 1 width=176 height=144 bytesPerRow=384>
<attributes=<CFBasicHash 0x12638bb0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf971b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "PixelFormatDescription"} = <CFBasicHash 0xb9fce0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf97164 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97194 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "OpenGLESCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    3 : <CFString 0x3bf972c4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ContainsAlpha"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e88 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = false}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf97184 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
    7 : <CFString 0x3bf972d4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "Planes"} = <CFArray 0xb24830 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <CFBasicHash 0xb99420 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf973b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0xba06a0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 12, capacity = 12, bytes = 0x00000000917cbb3100000000}
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf97334 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BlackBlock"} = <CFData 0xb9deb0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 1, capacity = 1, bytes = 0x10}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97324 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BitsPerBlock"} = <CFNumber 0xb277e0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

    1 : <CFBasicHash 0xba0e50 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf97334 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BlackBlock"} = <CFData 0xb9c550 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 2, capacity = 2, bytes = 0x8080}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf97344 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "HorizontalSubsampling"} = <CFNumber 0xc0f720 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +2, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    4 : <CFString 0x3bf97324 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "BitsPerBlock"} = <CFNumber 0xba0e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +16, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf973b4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0xba16d0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{length = 12, capacity = 12, bytes = 0x00000000817bbb3100000000}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf97354 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "VerticalSubsampling"} = <CFNumber 0xc0f720 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +2, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

)}
    8 : <CFString 0x3bf97294 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "PixelFormat"} = <CFNumber 0xb7acf0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +875704438, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    12 : <CFString 0x3bf97174 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3bf18e80 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = true}
}

}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x12638c10 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x3bf70edc [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "MetadataDictionary"} = <CFBasicHash 0x12638650 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x3bf70f4c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "SNR"} = <CFNumber 0x126367e0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +34.16280207318401096472, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x3bf70ddc [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "sensorDGain"} = <CFNumber 0x12633120 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +256, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x3bf70f3c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "SensorID"} = <CFNumber 0x126360c0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +38754, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf7054c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ExposureTime"} = <CFNumber 0x12636440 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +0.02999900000000000136, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
    7 : <CFString 0x3bf70dec [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ispDGain"} = <CFNumber 0x12630f20 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +260, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    11 : <CFString 0x3bf7017c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "AGC"} = <CFNumber 0xd580830 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +1803, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    12 : <CFString 0x3bf7114c [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "AEAverage"} = <CFNumber 0x12635ae0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{value = +176, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

    3 : <CFString 0x3bf96f54 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x126383d0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_601_4"}
    5 : <CFString 0x3bf96f94 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x12632d90 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    6 : <CFString 0x3bf96fd4 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x126372c0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x12638be0 [0x3bf18ad0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
>
```

Comment: Try compiling to 64 bit?

Comment: The bytes per row seems to be off on the planes. Can you experiment with a 640x480 preset and see if you have the same problem? Also, can you share some code especially related to the buffer delegate? Last, how are you viewing the image (preview layer?)

Comment: I don't need to have a preview layer I just encode the buffer and send it to RTP. On 640x480 is the same issue, is ok only on HD 720p.

Comment: And about 64 bit. I cannot build my project on 64 bit yet, I have included libs that are not able to support 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

As Spectravideo328 has mentioned the byte per row isn't the same as width of the image. Hence you'll need to copy the valid data from the source layers to your destination buffer skipping the extra paddings. That means for each row (which is equal to the "height" of the image) copy the first "width" amount of bytes.